# Linux text-only web browser that renders images in ASCII art

Tags: linux, web-browser, ascii

I remember having seen a screenshot of a Linux terminal-only (text) web browser, like `links` or `lynx`, but this one was able to **render images (in color) using ASCII art**.

Unfortunately I don't remember the name.  Does anyone know it, or have a suggestion for a similar software?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you're satisfied with [Browsh](https://www.brow.sh/):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9DwK.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I45yc.jpg]

> **Browsh is a fully-modern text-based browser.** It renders anything that a modern browser can; HTML5, CSS3, JS, video and even WebGL. Its main purpose is to be run on a remote server and accessed via SSH/Mosh or the in-browser HTML service in order to significantly reduce bandwidth and thus both increase browsing speeds and decrease bandwidth costs.

**Live SSH Demo**:

```
ssh brow.sh
```

> No auth needed. The service is for demonstration only, sessions last 5 minutes and are logged.

**Download** page: https://www.brow.sh/downloads

A **Docker image** is also available:

```
docker pull browsh/browsh
```

...or maybe you think about an [ascii-art image browser](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/index.html):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f9s8.jpg]

Comment: Yes, that was it!  Accepting your answer as you were the first one to suggest it.

Comment: Thank you @dr01! As you suggested, I merged my two answers into one.

Answer (score 8):

The browser [Browsh](https://www.brow.sh/) suggested by user simhumileco looks OK but the *images* are very low resolution.

Other suggestions are:

- [Lynx](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/) can [be configured](http://nixnik.50webs.com/lynx/00_main.html#edit) to display images using [aaview](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/) or [cacaview](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca).
- [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) can [be configured](http://wiki.schmid.dk/wiki/index.php?title=W3m) to display images using cacaview.

Aaview can produce images as good as this:

[image: Aaview Image]

Cacaview adds color, and can produce images as good as this:

[image: Cacaview Image]

---

**Other Retro Imaging**

**Related subject** information (not intended to directly answer *this* question):

- [RetroTxt](https://github.com/bengarrett/RetroTxt) can take old text and ASCII art images and display them on a modern browser using a [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/retrotxt/gkjkgilckngllkopkogcaiojfajanahn) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/retrotxt/) plugin. It allows selection of monospaced fonts for better viewing.
- Both [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) and [MPlayer](http://mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) can play modern videos rendered as ASCII art.

Not really related:

Android [WireGoggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dozingcatsoftware.WireGoggles&hl=en_CA) displays a real-time wireframe outline of what your camera is pointing at.

Android [Ascii Art Generator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duy.asciiart) converts images on your phone to ASCII art.